# idiots guide to getting presale ether and wallet

Tags: wallets

I've been looking over the responses for downloading presale ether and wallets. Honestly most of the answers require a strong programming background, which I don't have. I am looking for a safe, easy to understand way to do this as well as an understanding of the wallets and if they work the same as coin base and trezor. If there's a video somewhere even better. Thank you for taking time out to read my post.